# How to select records of a table with last related record on another table in T-sql

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two tables and i want to use some records from first table and get last related record from another one.

[You can see my tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCQ3I.jpg)

I want to join table 1 with last  record of table 2. (creationDate = 2018-07-20)

Comment: Make the question more specific like adding table structure or such?

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful with appropriate DBMS tag.

Comment: pls put an example of the tables an columns and wich column you need to check it's records, it's  too vast like this !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to get the latest record in table 2 for every ID in table one then this will work:

```
select t1.ID, t1.Name, q.ID, q.CreationDate
from table1 t1
outer apply
(
    select top 1 t2.ID, t2.CreationDate
    from table2 t2 
    where t2.tbl_1_Id = t1.ID
    order by t2.CreationDate desc
)q
```